# How to read a string with mixed nature in python

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, scanning

I have taken some data from a instrument. These data contain the temperature with time. A part of the data looks like,

```
00:00:08
section A 76.21
section B 76.54
section C 76.66
section D 77.87
00:15:30
section A 76.23
section B 76.89
section C 77.98
section D 78.60
…
```

and the file continues till end.
00:00:08 means 00 hour, 00 minutes, and 08 seconds.

Now I need to read this data and make a plot of the temperature with the time.

My code till now is following,

````
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from datetime import datetime
import re
def main():
file = r"C:\Users\sarad\ss1.dat.log"
index =[]
month =[]
day =[]
year =[]
hour =[]
minute =[]
second =[]
s1 =[]
s2 =[]
s3 =[]
s4 =[]
s5 =[]
s6 =[]
s7 =[]
s8 =[]
with open(file) as line:
while True:
result=re.findall(r"(\d+(?:.\d+){0,1})",line.read())
if not result:
break
hour.append(int((result[0])))
minute.append(int((result[1])))
second.append(int((result[2])))
s1.append(float(result[3]))
s2.append(float(result[4]))
s3.append(float(result[5]))
s4.append(float(result[6]))
s5.append(float(result[7]))
s6.append(float(result[8]))
s7.append(float(result[9]))
s8.append(float(result[10])) ```

I have to use loop somehow and read all the datas . 

Beside that i need to plot the datas vs time . How do i do that in code ? I tried with datetime function but that is not working. 

Could you give some idea ?

Thank you.

I described it in the previous section.
The python is 3.11 version.
````

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code you provided - we can guess, but you probably have a copy that doesn't look like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your text looks very well structured. It shouldn't be a problem to parse it. Here is how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

text = '''
00:00:08
section A 76.21
section B 76.54
section C 76.66
section D 77.87
00:15:30
section A 76.23
section B 76.89
section C 77.98
section D 78.60
'''

table = defaultdict(dict)
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if line:
        entry = line.strip()
        if ':' in entry:
            t = entry
        else:
            _, sample, data = entry.split()
            table[t].update({sample:float(data)})

print(table)
#defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'00:00:08': {'A': 76.21, 'B': 76.54, 'C': 76.66, 'D': 77.87}, '00:15:30': {'A': 76.23, 'B': 76.89, 'C': 77.98, 'D': 78.6}})


df = pd.DataFrame(table).T
print(df)
#              A      B      C      D
#00:00:08  76.21  76.54  76.66  77.87
#00:15:30  76.23  76.89  77.98  78.60



df.plot()
#set ticks labels and rotation
plt.xticks(
    ticks = range(len(df)),
    labels = df.index,
    rotation = 45
) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

To read from file:

```
file_name = 'myfile.txt'
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        entry = line.strip():
        if entry:

            if line.strip():
                if ':' in entry:
                t = entry
            else:
                _, sample, data = entry.split()
                table[t].update({sample:float(data)})
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. But i need to read the datas from a file. Can i read the file also using the code ?

Comment: I am getting the following error. I am working in windows 11.                                              File "C:\Users\sarad\py8.py", line 41, in main
    _, sample, data = entry.split()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta Sure, just read the file and process it similarly.

Comment: Yes, i  am reading the data. The problem the loop is not stopping in the last line. It is going to the next line where there is no data. Thats why it is showing value error. If I print the table inside loop then its fine. How to make sure that the file reading is stopped ?

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta that is another problem

Comment: I can read the datas from file but i want to stop reading at the last line. Could you please help in this regard ?

Comment: I have a new problem. While doing the plot the time is not updated . It is only showing the first time in the x axis. I need to use all the time in the x-axis.

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta that is just a matter of setting the `xticks` on the plot.  Check my last edit on the code.

Comment: Hii, I need to take the difference of the datas and as well as the time difference. So, that i can plot dT / dt against time. where dT is the difference between two data and dt is the difference between time.

Comment: @SaradinduSamanta I am not here to do your job. I have answered the question. If you have other problems, then you should open another thread.